# How Can I publish my game(made by unity) for google play after August 2019?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, build.gradle

I want publish my game but google store has Error
It need to 64 bit ad 86 bit support game ad Build App Bundle...
How producers publish their game?
How I can publish my game?
 I have unity2017.4.20 ad 2019.1.2
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 64 bit support and you can publish it to playstore.
Here is easy steps link how to enable it and it's supported unity versions.

https://www.hireunitydeveloper.com/android-64-bit-support-unity/

Comment: You can accept it as answer, if it solved your question.

Comment: No this is not enough because I can not publish on play store,I need a more complete response

Comment: I have added more details to it and now everything it needs to upload is there.
So you can follow and exact steps and done.